# When a sentence starts with "No" and has multiple subjects, which subject does the verb agree with?

Tags: verbs, subjects, agreement

Should it be "No juice and coffee are served," or "No juice and coffee is served?"

Comment: If there are several subjects, the verb should be plural, as with "A, B and C are not served."

Comment: It should be *No juice **or** coffee is/are served* (I have no particular opinion re singular or plural verb, but doubtless others will dispute that point).

Comment: I'd tend to try to avoid the questionable verb usage entirely: *"Neither juice nor coffee will be served."*.

Comment: Other conjunctions?  No drinks but coffee is/are served.

Comment: @GEdgar  '... other than' makes things easier.